# python else and elif error

Tags: python, if-statement

```
>>> if 5==5:
print '5'
else: print 'cat'

File "<pyshell#2>", line 3
else: print 'cat'
                ^
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

No matter what the indent is, it still doesn't work. Even if I try to put the `print cat` statement on the next line it gives me syntax error. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your code to look like this:

```
if 5 == 5:
    print '5'
else:
    print 'cat'
```

Why? Because Python uses indentation like other languages use brackets: it determines the grouping of statements. [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) has an excellent explanation of how this works:

> Python uses carriage returns to separate statements and a colon and indentation to separate code blocks. C++ and Java use semicolons to separate statements and curly braces to separate code blocks.

The [reference manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) also describes how this works at a lower level:

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.
>
> ...
>
> First, tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix). The total number of spaces preceding the first non-blank character then determines the line’s indentation.

Stylistically, you want to use 4 spaces to indicate a level of indentation. This is defined in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). This will ensure everyone sees the same thing, no matter what IDE they're using. Note that you should **never mix tabs and spaces**, as it becomes very easy to unwittingly break code (consider not all editors show tabs as the same size).

Answer (score 3):

Use proper indentation in python  otherwise you'll get such errors.

Use 4 spaces for indentation.

```
if 5 == 5:
    print '5'
else:
    print 'cat'
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

Comment: PEP8: `Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what your code is going to do, but note that it is impossible to print 'cat' out there. Therefore, the `else` statement is completely useless. Why? The `5==5` condition produces always `True`, so no matter what, `'5'` is always printed.